# Sci-fi novel involving living forever through teleporter copies

Tags: story-identification

In the novel they have worked out teleportation but the data is transmitted, meaning that they can make copies of it and generate multiple copies of a person if they choose to do so, or regenerate them if they get killed or injured.

A big part of the book was the use of micro-black holes as a building material, and the construction of a dyson sphere around the sun, along with terra-forming Venus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have described bears a strong resemblance to [Queendom of Sol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Queendom_of_Sol) series by Wil McCarthy.  Although I do not recall the Dyson sphere or terraforming Venus, it has been awhile since I have read the first two books in the series (and I have not read the third and fourth books).

The major construction material in the series is collapsium which is made from extremely dense matter and is programmable.  The characters travel throughout the Solar System by creating copies of themselves.

In addition to these backups created in various locations, humans had developed technology to indefinitely prolong the human lifespan.  Humans only died by accidents or murder.

Comment: That's it.  It was the first one of the series that I read... although I had gotten the impression it was in the middle of the series when I did :)  Thanks!